# The URL will not let me to add order and description

Tags: c#, url, model-view-controller, payment

This is how I should have added an order idea and description for payment on the home. but when I debugger URL gives me error as it provides added order and description of the URL.

```
var order = DateTime.Now.Year + Helper.Settings.NyTal(4);
var description = "&description=Medlemskab";
var client = new RestClient("http://api.blabla.net/subscriptions?currency=dkk&order_id=" + order + description);
```

Comment: Did you just compromise something by showing the world that "authorization" header?

Comment: @BobKaufman What do you completely?

Comment: Is that "authorization" header some secret token that the rest of the world isn't supposed to see? If an unscrupulous user were to copy those headers into his own program, could he do something that would cost you lots of money? If so, you'll want to revoke that token promptly and get a new one issued.

Comment: **Strongly** agree with Bob Kaufman..

Comment: @BobKaufman I don't think English is his strong suit. J. Peterson, you should request a new **authorization** key if that is connected to your personal account and somebody could do bad things to you should they know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        var order = DateTime.Now.Year + Helper.Settings.NyTal(4);
        var description = "&description=Medlemskab";
        var request = string.Format("http://api.blabla.net/subscriptions?currency=dkk&order_id={0}{1}", order, description);
        var client = new RestClient(request);
```

See if that works, if it doesn't I'll delete this. Might just be a conversion issue as you're trying to append an `int` to `string` directly without converting it beforehand.

Alternatively:

```
var order = DateTime.Now.Year + Helper.Settings.NyTal(4); //.ToString()
var description = "&description=Medlemskab";
var client = new RestClient("http://api.blabla.net/subscriptions?currency=dkk&order_id=" + order.ToString() + description);
```

Whatever floats your boat. As I said, I'll delete this if I'm wrong.

Comment: It should in no against Accept it. I findet here as I try:

[link her](http://tech.quickpay.net/api/services/?scope=merchant#POST-subscriptions---format-)

Comment: It says it requires a full string value in the documentation. `var order = ...` is an `int` and you're trying to directly append it to a string here `RestClient("http://api.blabla.net/subscriptions?currency=dkk&order_id=" + order + description);` You cannot append an `int` directly to a `string` without converting to one

Comment: Its work now for me.! :) Thanks for it help!! :) Good day to u

Comment: No problem - happy to help

Comment: @J.Petersen Check out the comments in the first post. It's important you make sure that **Authorization** key you have in the image isn't going to hurt you in anyway if somebody uses it